# Form input field not displaying previous data correct

Tags: php

With the following code I need to be able to enter a tracking pixel code which contains these `" & ?` characters.
With the below code it allows entry of the pixel in the **textbox** saving it and the resulting line in the file is correct.
However when it then reloads the pixel for display in the value in the form field it has been cut off.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["pixel"])) {
  $fp = fopen("config.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file config file");
  fwrite($fp, $_POST["pixel"]."\n");
  fclose($fp);
}
$fp = fopen("configz.php", "r") or die("Unable to open config file");
$pixel = fgets($fp);
fclose($fp);
?>
<form method="post">
Pixel:<input type="text" name="pixel" value="<?=$pixel?>" />
<input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save">
</form>
```

[image: pixel entered]
[image: pixel displayed]

Comment: Syntax error here. value=""<?=($pixel)?>" it should be value="<?=($pixel)?>"

Comment: thanks but thats just a mistype when i shortened the code for here. the original code only has "

Comment: I was trying a bunch of functions to try to fix it like urlencode, unldecode, etc

Comment: What value are you getting in $pixel?

Comment: modified original to include pictures. first pic is pixel entered. 2nd pic is after saved, loaded, and displayed in value.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change below code

```
<input type="text" name="pixel" value="<?=$pixel?>" />
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="pixel" value='<?=$pixel?>' />
```

Add single '' around value as in your $pixel string you have "". It will break the string from the first occurrence of " in $pixel.

### Edit

You can replace all single quote with double quotes.

### JS

```
var b = a.replace(/'/g, '"');
```

where a will be your string.

### PHP

```
$pixel = str_replace("'", '"', $pixel);
```

### Update

To replace all double quotes with single quotes in form input.

```
var newVal = [];

$('#form_id *').filter(':input').each(function(){
  var k = $(this).attr('name');
  var v = $(this).val();
  newVal[key] = v.replace(/'/g, '"');
});
```

You can loop through all the values of the form and get their name as a key, get all values, perform replace on all values and add `key=>value` pair in an empty array. In `newVal` you will have the desired output which you can use.

Comment: that worked great. my concern now is if someone enters pixel code with single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: Also please mark as approved if it helped. Thanks. :) @EdNewman

Comment: the php is actually backwards but I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way in javascript to replace all double quotes with single quotes in all form fields when they submit the form.
I have like 50 fields and having to do the php method on each field is cumbersome.

Comment: See my last update in answer. @EdNewman let me know if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST["pixel"])) {
   $fp = fopen("config.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file config 
   file");
   fwrite($fp, $_POST["pixel"]."\n");
   fclose($fp);
}
$fp = fopen("configz.php", "r") or die("Unable to open config file");
$pixel = fgets($fp);
fclose($fp);
?>
<form method="post">

    Pixel:<input type="text" name="pixel" value='<?=$pixel?>' /> 

  <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save">
</form>
```

Add a single quote instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue by leaving all the code as it was originally and just changing the fgets line.
This allows the field to have single or double quotes in it and displays the data correctly.
not letting me post it. it changes it here.
[image]